# Speech Recognition Loop

Tags: c#, windows, service, windows-services, speech-recognition

My question is simply how to implement speech recognition in a windows service in such a way that the service is continuously listening for something to be spoken.


I have done a bit of research and it seems that the solution would be to use a timer and "listen" for speech at specific intervals, although this seems to be wrong to me. Any thoughts or comments would help really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you building a speech recognition engine or integrating into an existing ASR? A timer will not work. You need a listener that is always listening. Listening for detection on the beginning of speech and the endpoint of any utterances. A timer could miss the beginning of speech.

Comment: I am using the system.speech.recognition engine.

Comment: Why do you need a loop?  SpeechRecognitionEngine has its own listener that is activated when you call the Recognize method. You just need to handle the events it throws.

Comment: Ah yes I see that now. I never saw the SpeechRecognized event in the engine. Thank you for clearing things up for me!